# Obtain the free_memory value in xen

Tags: xen, memory-usage, shell-scripting

I would like to know if there's an alternative to the command I am currently using to get the real free memory for the system (meaning memory that can be assigned to new domU)

```
xm info | grep free_memory
```

I have a script that reads several parameters of the server (such as disc ocupation and so on), and can't take more than about 10 seconds, and the information /proc/meminfo is only relative to dom0, not the system.

The time to process the tat fom xm info is about 100ms usually, but many times goes over 1sec

Some time ago, I faced the same issues while calculating the size of the lvm volumes [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/168439/quickest-way-to-determine-size-of-a-block-device) so I'm trying it again :)